# undefined variable created from array index search JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I have created a variable from a selected index in an array. Inside the selected index I get a string value. When I step through this I can see the value, but the variable is "undefined". When passing that variable after the creation is completed it remains undefined.

"numResult" is the user defined selection from the array.

```
var faddress = geocodeResults[numResult].address.value;

showResults.infoTemplate.setContent("<b>Name: " + faddress + "</b>");
```

Comment: Can you show `geocodeResults` structure ?

Comment: It's very hard to tell without knowing what is the exact value of `numResult` and `geocodeResults`.

Comment: to test I've passed in the first index here is some info from the call stack: `geocodeResults: Array[50]
0: a
address: "New York City, New York, United States"
attributes: Object
location: a
score: 100
__proto__: Object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove .value, the call stack was undefined because of .val..... over analyzed again

Thanks everyone